# Is someone who is unable to believe in Allah a heretic?

Tags: belief, theology, imaan, atheists

Suppose someone really truly wants to believe in Allah, but is simply unable to. Even after much trying and learning, he still is simply unable to believe in God. Would that person be considered a heretic? Is there anything that he can do to not be a heretic?

Comment: +1:what do you mean by heretic? People who dont believe in Allah are atheists which is worse then being  a heretic(innovator in religion)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFUfA6O0V4A

Comment: Simply ask God for guidance. We can only comprehend that which God has given us the ability to comprehend.

Comment: @MumtazAhmed If he doesn't believe in God, then he won't ask God for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I think,from my point of view, this person that can't generate his proof that Allah exists because he is choosing the wrong way of generating the proof , learning would help to understand the truth about Allah but it would be more and more unreal if this one is unfamiliar with notations  or his axioms consider what he reads is wrong,so I would give that person an advise to start building new axioms that is : new axioms that would lead to believe in Allah .
As a Muslim what I do often is to keep focused in the main reason why god create us , I don't think why god exists because it must do otherwise who make all these wonderful things we are seeing ? such as the creation of man ! science reveal the complex structure of cells it is organized in way that no coincidence would do it ever ! other example is the organization of the atom,on can see the similarity to the solar system !! so what make these things to be similar ? the last example is the big bang nowadays it is a truth but it was mentioned in the Quran 1400 years ago !!! the answer is Allah he make this organized structure of the universe and all things !!

Comment: As a Muslim, one's belief in God is an axiom in his model. There is nothing to prove or disprove for a Muslim, an axiom is like a belief, we accept it.

Comment: yes this form a proof ! and this a sign from god as mentioned in quran , so if you look in surah "almulk" you will read that "there is no differences between what alrhman creat " "ما ترى في خلق الرحمن من تفاوت " this is exactly what I tried to say !

Answer (score 1):

God and His existence is very large concept, may not be readily there to take in.

Some things are "felt" even before proven by deductive science. 
I don't think Einstein sat at his desk and played with formulas 
for writing his theory. He's first seen and observed many things, 
"sensed" how it can be-- that without anything behind supporting in any way 
what he "saw". He then modelled and proved what still is difficult for a great majority to comprehend even today.

Human beings are equipped with many forms 
of understanding and perceptions. What we see and realize build on 
our conscious, mind, emotions, beliefs, ... . If it can be put into 
clear-cut philosophy that's perfectly fine. 
But i think closing the door to what we 
can see but not prove would be missing a very big part of it.

Too lengthy for a comment-- that's why here.

Totally my personal opinion-- not a scholar on the subject.

Comment: That's actually the exact opposite of what Einstein did, as it is contrary to the scientific method. Nevertheless, I get your point so +1

Comment: that's refute without point. however, i've got your point-- i think.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose someone really truly wants to believe in Allah, but is simply unable to. Even after much trying and learning, he still is simply unable to believe in God. Would that person be considered a heretic?

Let's define heretic..

> Heretic: a belief which is against the principles of a particular religion (Cambridge Dictionary)

**Yes**, because the fundamental notion of Islam is that you believe that there is something called 'God', who [created *you and Mars*](http://quran.com/4/131) and [what ever you could see with your eyes and what ever you couldn't see with your eyes](http://quran.com/59/22).

---

> Is there anything that he can do to not be a heretic?

The concept of [free will](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_in_Islam) comes into the picture. **#e.g.** I think this case is analogous to a believer who isn't very much strong in his faith about Allah and after life, wishing to offer Salah (prayers), but couldn't no matter how hard he tried, he is just unable to. We say that, **he is not being guided by God.** And [God guides as he wishes](http://quran.com/2/272), to whom ever he wishes.

The problem of Atheism is there not only in this era, but from back in the past, e.g. Pharaoh of the time of Moses (pbuh). The people of their era do not get convinced that there is something called God, because either they're too proud or they think they've unraveled the science of creation and existence, which makes them believe everything existed on its own.

The Iman / faith about God has to be created in his heart to cross the line of your case's person to believing in God. Your case, is quite contrary, and as I said is analogous to that e.g. #e.g. which I gave. In both the cases, they think they have faith, but they don't completely have it or they don't have it to the level it is required for their task to get completed.

It is impossible to happen, that a person is requesting God with whole heartedly to guide him, and yet, God is not guiding. If he would've asked God sincerely, then surely God would've guided. Again, as I said, this is a very complicated issue in Islam, the free will thing. Always, people from different sects, have varied opinions on this matter. Again...

> Is there anything that he can do to not be a heretic?

To have faith in God, first of all **he must try**. And in this case, **he is actually not trying**, but he thinks he is trying. He first, has to believe i.e. cross the boundary and then ask God to guide him, then God might guide him. I hope the two comments (#[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/is-someone-who-is-unable-to-believe-in-allah-a-heretic#comment16173_8164) #[2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/is-someone-who-is-unable-to-believe-in-allah-a-heretic#comment16513_8164)) below your question support my point of contradiction. Until he actually tries, no matter how hard he tries, it is almost impossible to believe.

May the creator guide us all.